# Bootstrap Tabs as Hugo Shortcodes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, hugo, bootstrap-tabs, hugo-shortcode

I am trying to create a shortcode for bootstrap tabs. I have following HTML structure,

```
<nav class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="{{ .Get `id` }}-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ .Get `id` }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ .Get `id` }}">
      {{ .Get "title" }}
  </a>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="{{ .Get `id` }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="{{ .Get `id` }}-tab">
    {{ .Inner }}
  </div>
</div>
```

The structure also contains the Hugo placeholder. But the inner part of the code, which is,

```
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="{{ .Get `id` }}-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ .Get `id` }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ .Get `id` }}">
      {{ .Get "title" }}
  </a>
```

is required multiple times along with the corresponding content div which is,

```
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="{{ .Get `id` }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="{{ .Get `id` }}-tab">
    {{ .Inner }}
  </div>
```

Now the problem is that I have to pass the `id` as an argument of inner structure and should be detached from its parent. I should be able to use shortcode in following way:

```
{% tabs %}
    {% tab id = "tab-1" title = "Tab One" %}
        Content in Tab 1
    {% \tab %}
    {% tab id = "tab-2" title = "Tab Two" %}
        Content in Tab 2
    {% \tab %}
{% \tabs %}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to iterate over the child shortcodes and extract their values in order to include them in the parent shortcode construct.

I suggest you create a custom param in the front matter (call it 'tabs' for instance) and iterate over its values in your 'tags' shortcode:
`range .Page.Params.tabs`

I know it's redundant and hacky but it's the simplest way to get it working. The other way I know is much more involved and complicated and I am not sure it's worth the effort, but it is fully automated. It involves creating a content page for every tab, ugh.

Answer (score 0):

The following two shortcodes will achieve what you want:

**tabs.html**

```
<!-- Scratchpad gets populated through call to .Inner -->  
{{- .Inner -}}

<nav class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs-{{- $.Ordinal -}}" role="tablist">
  {{- range $index, $element := $.Scratch.Get "tabs" -}}
    <!-- Generate the IDs for the <a> and the <div> elements -->
    {{- $tabid := printf "tab-%v-%v-tab" $.Ordinal $index | anchorize -}}
    {{- $entryid := printf "tab-%v-%v" $.Ordinal $index | anchorize -}}
    <a class="nav-item nav-link{{ if eq $index "0" }} active{{ end }}"
      id="{{ $tabid }}" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ $entryid }}" role="tab"
      aria-controls="{{ $tabid }}" aria-selected="{{- cond (eq $index "0") "true" "false" -}}">
      {{ index . "title" }}
    </a>
  {{- end -}}
  </nav>

<!-- Inner content -->
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs-{{- $.Ordinal -}}-content">
  {{- range $index, $element := $.Scratch.Get "tabs" -}}
    {{- $tabid := printf "tab-%v-%v-tab" $.Ordinal $index | anchorize -}}
    {{- $entryid := printf "tab-%v-%v" $.Ordinal $index | anchorize -}}
    <div class="tab-pane fade{{ if eq $index "0" }} show active{{ end }}"
        id="{{ $entryid }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelled-by="{{ $tabid }}">
    {{- highlight (index . "content") "" "" -}}
     </div>
  {{ end }}
</div>
```

**tab.html**

```
<!-- Prefill title if not given as parameter -->
{{ $title := default (printf "Tab %v" ( add $.Ordinal 1)) (.Get "title") }}

<!-- store all tab info in dict tab -->
{{ $tab := dict "title" $title }}
{{ $tab = merge $tab (dict "content" (trim $.Inner "\n")) }}

<!-- add dict tab to parent's scratchpad -->
{{- $.Parent.Scratch.SetInMap "tabs" (printf "%v" $.Ordinal) $tab -}}
```

You can then use the shortcodes inside your page as shown below:

**PageWithTabbedPane.md**

```
## Tabbed pane

{{< tabs >}}
    {{< tab title = "Tab One" >}}
Content in Tab 1
    {{< /tab >}}
    {{< tab title = "Tab Two" >}}
Content in Tab 2
    {{< /tab >}}
{{< /tabs >}}
```

With the presented solution, there is no need to specify an `id` inside the markup of the tabbed pane. Also, if you omit the `title` parameter of the tab, the title defaults to `Tab n`.

Please note that this is the bare-bone version of the shortcodes. You may extend the shortcodes with named parameters `lang` and/or `highlight`. The values of these optional parameters could be passed on as second `LANG` and third `OPTIONS` arguments to Hugo’s built-in [highlight](https://gohugo.io/functions/highlight/) function which is used to render the code blocks of the individual tabs.

You may have a look at the advanced shortcodes [tabpane.html](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/docsy/master/layouts/shortcodes/tabpane.html) and [tab.html](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/docsy/master/layouts/shortcodes/tab.html), together with their according [description](https://www.docsy.dev/docs/adding-content/shortcodes/#tabbed-panes).